# Equilibrium between two thermodynamic phases : equality of gibbs potentials

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I work in $(T,P,N)$ ensemble.

I am studying a phase transition between a liquid and gas phase for the Van Der Waals model.

In the pdf I am reading they say that when the two phases are at equilibrium, we have :

$$G_1(T,P_V)=G_2(T,P_V)$$

Where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the gibbs energy of the liquid and gas phases.

But I don't understand this equality.

Indeed for me we have by extensivity :

$$G=G_1+G_2$$

And we know that $G_1=\mu_1 N_1$, $G_2=\mu_2 N_2$ (Euler Identity for Gibbs energy).

What's more, the chemical potential of the phases are equal because the two phases are at equilibrium.

Then we have :

$$G=G_1+G_2=\mu(N_1+N_2)$$

$G_1(T,P_V)=G_2(T,P_V)$ would then mean that $N_1=N_2$

But I know that this result is not true.

**Where am I wrong in my derivation ?**

Remark : The equality between the Gibbs functions is given in the page before the last one of this document :

https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~valenti/WS13-14/all_1314_chap6.pdf

Comment: I think the equilibrium condition should really be $\mu_1=\mu_2$, in case the total number of molecules does not change in the phase transition. The molar Gibbs free energies (chemical potentials) of the two phases should be equal.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe hmmm ok. I edited my message with the link of the PDF I am referring to. Do you have an Idea of why they write an equality between the gibbs energy ? (And yes, $N=N_1+N_2$ is indeed a constant in the whole problem i posed).

Comment: Perhaps they mean molar Gibbs energy. It is convenient to write the Van der Waals equation for $1\,\mathrm{mol}$ of molecules. In general $G$ is a function of $T,P,N$. If somehow it only depends on two variables, it is implied that the third one is fixed.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe oh, ok. Then in fact their $G_1$ and $G_2$ are exactly the $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ right ? Because if they talk about per mol it would mean they talk about $\frac{\partial G} {\partial N}=\mu$. Is it what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, and also because $G=\mu N$.

Comment: An interesting example for the equilibrium condition not to be $\mu_1=\mu_2$ is the dissociation of $\mathrm{N}_2\mathrm{O}_4\leftrightarrow 2\mathrm{NO}_2$. For this chemical reaction to be balanced, $\mu_{N_2O_4}=2\mu_{NO_2}$ because $1\,\mathrm{mol}$ of $\mathrm{N}_2\mathrm{O}_4$ becomes $2\,\mathrm{mol}$ of $\mathrm{NO}_2$.

Comment: You're aware that if you start off with one mole of a saturated liquid at T and P and add heat reversibly at constant temperature and pressure to completely evaporate it to a saturated vapor at the same temperature and pressure, the amount of heat you add Q is equal to the change in enthalpy (i.e., heat of vaporization) $\Delta H$, correct?  And, because the process is reversible and at constant temperature, Q is also equal to $T\Delta S$.  So, $$Q=\Delta H=T\Delta S$$So, $$\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S=0$$So, the molar free energy of the vapor is equal to the molar free energy of the liquid.

Comment: Why would equilibrium imply that $G_1 = G_2$?  You may be confusing "states 1 and 2 (of the combined system)" with "subsystems 1 and 2, each with a different phase."  Indeed, for equilibrium, you must have $dG = 0$, or $dG_1 = -dG_2$, which is inconsistent with $G_1 = G_2$.

Comment: The equality in your question is not true. It is the cause of results that you don't understand. The equilibrium state is when the free energy is at the minimum or its derivative is zero.